# How to insert values in one column with respect to the value of other column of a table

Tags: database, oracle

I have the following table `result`:

```
roll integer 
c_id varchar(20)
marks number(6,2)
grade varchar(6)
gpa number(3,2)
cgpa number(3,2)
year varchar(10)
term varchar(10)
```

And `courses` and `student` tables. I have entered into `result` table the marks of courses and want to assign the corresponding grade in the grade column. I want to insert A+ in grade column for marks of greater than or equal to 240, A for greater than equal to 210 and less than 240.

How can I do it?

Here is the DDL:

```
drop table result;
drop table courses;
drop table student;
create table student(
roll number(10),
fname varchar(30),
lname varchar(30),
department varchar(50)
);
ALTER TABLE student ADD PRIMARY KEY (roll)

create table courses(
c_id varchar(30) NOT NULL,
c_name varchar(30), 
credit integer CHECK(credit>0 and credit<5)
);    
ALTER TABLE COURSES ADD PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
ALTER TABLE COURSES ADD UNIQUE KEY (c_id)
create table result(
roll number(10),
c_id varchar(30),
marks number (6,2),
year varchar (10),
term varchar (10),
gpa number(3,2),
cgpa number(3,2),
grade varchar (4)
);
ALTER TABLE result ADD FOREIGN KEY (roll) REFERENCES student(roll)
ALTER TABLE result ADD FOREIGN KEY (c_id) REFERENCES courses(c_id)
```

Here is the result data:

```
insert into result (roll,c_id,marks,year,term) values (1307019,'cse 3103',200,'2nd','1st');
insert into result (roll,c_id,marks,year,term) values (1307019,'cse 3105',210,'2nd','1st');
insert into result (roll,c_id,marks,year,term) values (1307019,'cse 3107',190,'2nd','1st');
```

Comment: Why do you add both a primary key AND a unique key on the same column in the same table? You should (probably) add a compound primary key on `results`, from `roll, c_id, year, term`. Then - why do you keep "gpa" in the same table where you keep grades for individual courses? "gpa" should be computed, not stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `update` statement with a conditional expression to alter the existing data and fill the `grade` column.

This should work:

```
update result 
set grade = 
  case 
    when marks >= 240 then 'A+'
    when marks >= 210 and marks < 240 then 'A'
    -- continue adding more clauses below
    -- else 'B' -- maybe a default value?
  end;
```

Comment: @ashik I don't know. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @ashik Maybe a silly question, but are you executing the update before you do the select?

Answer (score 1):

try this database compound trigger

here i give you database trigger which will be fire on table while you are inserting or updating records and this can be accomplished with specific condition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_result
  FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON result
  COMPOUND TRIGGER
  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    CASE

      WHEN INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN
        :NEW.GRADE := (CASE
                        WHEN :NEW.marks >= 240 THEN
                         'A+'
                        WHEN :NEW.marks >= 210 and :NEW.marks < 240 THEN
                         'A'
                        ELSE
                         'B'
                      END);

    END CASE;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;

END trg_result;
```

main benefits of trigger is we can update automatically grade which is depends on marks while insert and update in your example.

after create trigger fire your insert statement again and see result.your grade column is insert as specified condition.

full description of compound trigger is here

https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1

i hope this may help.

Comment: if we use update then its compulsory to fire again on data change.

Answer (score 1):

There are two natural ways to do this. To illustrate I simplify the problem (in comments to the original question I pointed out a couple of things that should be changed in the setup).

**Virtual column** approach:

```
create table results (
roll number,
c_id number,
mark number(6,2),                      -- why "marks"? it should be "mark"
grade varchar(6) as (                  -- oversimplified, change as needed
     case when mark >= 240 then 'A+'
          when mark >= 210 then 'A'
          else                  'F--'
          end
   )
);
```

In this arrangement, you only insert values for  `roll, c_id, s_id, mark` - if you try to also enter a value for `grade` you will get an error message. Used like this:

```
SQL> insert into results (roll, c_id, mark) values (322245, 316, 235);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into results (roll, c_id, mark) values (322673, 316, 190);

1 row created.


SQL> select * from results;

      ROLL       C_ID       MARK GRADE
---------- ---------- ---------- ------
    322245        316        235 A
    322673        316        190 F--

2 rows selected.
```

The biggest weakness of this approach is that the breakpoints for the different letter grades are hard-coded directly in the table definition.

The better approach is:

**View**

Create a separate table with `c_id, year, term`, and minimum required score for each letter grade. This is maintained separately from the `results` table.

Then create a VIEW joining the `results` table and this helper table to compute the letter grade from the mark, joining on `c_id, year, term` and a more complicated condition on `mark`.

Not sure the OP wants to go that far; I can post a simple implementation of this approach if desired.